# Is useful/interesting to combine Carleman's inequality with sequences arising from analytic number theory?

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, soft-question, asymptotics, analytic-number-theory

I would like to know if the following comparison, of series involving sequences arising from analytic number theory and the so-called Carleman's inequality, is potentitally interesting. Thus I am asking it as a sof question or well to know what about it, or if this idea was in the literature.

One has the Wikipedia article dedicated to the Carleman's inequality, [is this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carleman%27s_inequality). On the other hand one has sequences $a_n$ of positive integers or non-negative real numbers from analytic number theory. For example $\frac{2+\mu(n)}{n^{x}}$ where $\mu(n)$ is the Möbius function and $x>1$, other example is $|G_n|$ where $G_n$ is the $n$th Gregory coefficient (see this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregory_coefficients)), or finally this example of $a_n=\frac{1}{p_n}+\frac{1}{2+p_n}$, where $p_n$ is prime and $p_n+2$ also is prime.

> **Question.** Imagine that a friend asks me if is interesting to write the specializations of Carleman's inequality that I've evoked. That is, if the resulting inequalities have a good mathematical meaning: are sharper inequalitites (are good, or very difficult to improve), or are showing some interesting fact about some of our sequence $a_n$. What should I say to him/her?*  **Many thanks.**

*If you argue that this inequality might not be very good for some of my sequences, or the calculations are tedious, please explain your words in your  answer of the previous question.

Also you can to illustrate your words with different sequences from analytic number theory.

Comment: Everyone goodnight, I believe that this question is interesting because I don't know if such approach was in the literature and because one can to explore such (amazing) inequalities. I would like to know a 
reasoning to rule out or confirm the use of such a strategy :)

Comment: Many thanks @Rohan now I see your reference.

Answer (score 0):

I am not perfectly sure, but I found a reference from [Edgar Krahn 1884-1961, A Centenary Volume ; Lumiste and Lumiste](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=tDG1osMCRrYC&pg=PA98&lpg=PA98&dq=carleman%27s+inequality+and+analytic+number+theory&source=bl&ots=X4Em8Jg2DK&sig=dBpbWlg9FYcGb8K7P84Rg8_Di8U&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjor663hNrYAhWIiLwKHZlkC2MQ6AEwCHoECA0QAQ#v=onepage&q=carleman's%20inequality%20and%20analytic%20number%20theory&f=false).

Also, see this [interesting paper](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.389.5541%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf&ved=2ahUKEwiWhI-87NzYAhUL2LwKHW2ZApQQFjAFegQICxAB&usg=AOvVaw3eL_qgkjrBB5i9nyS7Z-h9).

Comment: Also a search of *Carleman's inequality* in Google may help.

Comment: Many thanks for your attention and help.